# Joomla 4 Search Engine Friendly URLs make link broken

Tags: joomla-4.x, sef

I'm having the problem of wrong image links when "Search Engine Friendly URLs" is enabled, I'm also having "Use URL Rewriting" enabled.
For example, I'm on domain/abc page, when checking the srouce, the image will be "images/....", but when hovering on the image's src it shows as "domain/abc/images/. .." not "domain/images/...".
SYS - SEF plugin enabled.
Changed htaccess.txt to .htaccess.
Update: This error is only with php 8 version, I tried it on php 7 and everything works normally.